# bash script that get first 5 lines and put in another file

Tags: linux, bash

hi all i need to write a simple bash script that lists all PHP files in a directory and writes the first 5 lines of each PHP-file to new file called : PHP_header

i know only the basic in linux command line

```
#!/bin/bash
    grep –r stringsearch
    find /opt/-name ‘log_*’
    du –s foldername
    head -10 filename
    mkdir filername.php
```

please explain me how can i complet this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.php; do
  head -5 "$f"
done > PHP_header
```

To add some explanation:

- `for f in *.php`

  The loop iterates over all `.php` files in the current working directory.
- `head -5`

  This command prints the first five lines of a file to `STDOUT`.
- `done > PHP_header`

  The redirection (`>`) at the end of the loop redirects `STDOUT` for everything printed inside the loop to the file `PHP_header`.